# Aggregate by paymentamount

Tags: r

I have data like this:

```
emailaddress    customer_acquisation_date  customer_order_date  payment_amount
xy@gmail.com     01/05/2013 6:24 AM         01/05/2013 5:10 AM           $ 20.67
xy@gmail.com     01/05/2013 6:24 AM         02/07/2013 7:21 PM           $ 25.56
xy@gmail.com     01/05/2013 6:24 AM         07/10/2013 8:00 AM           $100.00
xy@gmail.com     01/05/2013 6:24 AM         08/12/2013 9:35 AM           $30.00
```

I am trying to sum(payment amount) by emailaddress where i want final output as:

```
emailaddress    customer_acquisation_date  customer_order_date  payment_amount
xy@gmail.com     01/05/2013 6:24 AM         01/05/2013            $ 177
                                            02/07/2013                 
                                            07/10/2013                 
                                            08/12/2013
```

code I am writing

```
z <- aggregate(x$emailaddress~x$paymentamount,data=x,FUN=sum)
```

Error I am getting

```
Error in Summary.factor(c(211594L, 291939L, 79240L, 208971L, 369325L,  : 
  ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors
```

What is right way of doing this. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The aggregate function first takes a value to aggregate on, then the grouping argument. As mentioned, you also need to remove the dollar sign to be able to convert the column to numeric format.

```
# Remove the dollar sign
x$payment_amount = as.numeric( gsub('[$]', '', x$payment_amount ))

# Write it in the right order .. aggregate(x, by, FUN .. ) 
z <- aggregate( payment_amount ~ emailaddress, data = x, FUN = sum )
```

**Edit:** Adding a data.table solution, keeping the other columns as well.

```
 library(data.table)  
 setDT(x) # Convert the data.frame to data.table
 z = x[, payment_total := sum(payment_amount), by = emailaddress]
 setDF(z) # Convert the result to data.frame
```

Comment: Nice - much faster data.table solution +1

Answer (score 2):

Instead of removing the `$` sign, the following extracts the numeric value directly. This has the benefit of not needing to specify what to actually remove (e.g. different currency signs, or "10.00 USD"). I've also added `merge` to get exactly OP's desired output (not really, but better IMHO):

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

x$payment_amount %<>% {regmatches(., gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+[.][[:digit:]]+", .))} %>%
  as.numeric() 

aggre = aggregate(payment_amount ~ emailaddress, data = df, FUN = sum)

select(x, -payment_amount) %>%
  merge(aggre, by = "emailaddress") %>%
  rename(tot_payment_amount = payment_amount)
```

Result:

```
  emailaddress customer_acquisation_date customer_order_date tot_payment_amount
1 xy@gmail.com        01/05/2013 6:24 AM  01/05/2013 5:10 AM             176.23
2 xy@gmail.com        01/05/2013 6:24 AM  02/07/2013 7:21 PM             176.23
3 xy@gmail.com        01/05/2013 6:24 AM  07/10/2013 8:00 AM             176.23
4 xy@gmail.com        01/05/2013 6:24 AM  08/12/2013 9:35 AM             176.23
```

Note:

I used the `magrittr` package mainly for it's convenient two-way pipe operator `%<>%`. This feeds the LHS (`x$payment_amount`) to the `.`'s on the RHS and sets the LHS equal to the output of RHS. `{}` around `regmatches` is required to feed `x$payment_amount` into a function within a function (i.e. `text=` argument of `gregexpr` that is inside `regmatches`). For those who find `%<>%` to be confusing, here is how to do the same without `%<>%`:

```
x$payment_amount = 
  with(x, regmatches(payment_amount, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+[.][[:digit:]]+", payment_amount))) %>%
  as.numeric()
```

Answer (score 0):

We could not add character or factor together. We need to convert the factor to character, remove `$`, and then convert to numeric.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

x2 <- x %>%
  mutate(payment_amount = as.character(payment_amount)) %>%
  mutate(payment_amount = str_replace(payment_amount, fixed("$"), "")) %>%
  mutate(payment_amount = as.numeric(payment_amount)) %>%
  group_by(emailaddress) %>%
  summarise(payment_amount = sum(payment_amount))

x2
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  emailaddress payment_amount
        <fctr>          <dbl>
1 xy@gmail.com         176.23
```

**Data**

```
x <- read.table(text = "emailaddress    customer_acquisation_date  customer_order_date  payment_amount
xy@gmail.com     '01/05/2013 6:24 AM'         '01/05/2013 5:10 AM'           '$ 20.67'
                xy@gmail.com     '01/05/2013 6:24 AM'         '02/07/2013 7:21 PM'           '$ 25.56'
                xy@gmail.com     '01/05/2013 6:24 AM'         '07/10/2013 8:00 AM'           '$100.00'
                xy@gmail.com     '01/05/2013 6:24 AM'         '08/12/2013 9:35 AM'           '$30.00'",
                header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanku for solution but it is giving me error Error in x %>% mutate(paymentamount = as.character(paymentamount)) %>%  : 
  could not find function "%>%"

Comment: @sim you need to load the `dplyr` package with `library(dplyr)`

Comment: Did you load the `dplyr` package by `library(dplyr)`?

Comment: @ycw..yes I loaded the dplyr..now got that error resolved but getting new one..Error in mutate(paymentamount = as.character(paymentamount)) : 
  object 'paymentamount' not found

Comment: It is a typo. it should be `payment_amount`.

Comment: @ycw..but i dont have payment_amount in my data..the column name is paymentamount?

Comment: I created the data frame based on the example you gave. You specified it to be `payment_amount`, not me.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `readr`, `dplyr`, and `lubridate`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

data_string <- trimws('
email        , datetime           , payment
xy@gmail.com , 01/05/2013 5:10 AM , $20.67
xy@gmail.com , 02/07/2013 7:21 PM , $25.56
xy@gmail.com , 07/10/2013 8:00 AM , $100.00
xy@gmail.com , 08/12/2013 9:35 AM , $30.00
')

orders <- read_csv(data_string, col_types = cols(
    email = col_character(),
    datetime = col_datetime(format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p"),
    payment = col_number()
))
orders

## # A tibble: 4 x 3
##          email            datetime payment
##          <chr>              <dttm>   <dbl>
## 1 xy@gmail.com 2013-01-05 05:10:00   20.67
## 2 xy@gmail.com 2013-02-07 19:21:00   25.56
## 3 xy@gmail.com 2013-07-10 08:00:00  100.00
## 4 xy@gmail.com 2013-08-12 09:35:00   30.00

customers <- orders %>%
    group_by(email) %>%
    summarise(
        total_payment = sum(payment),
        acquisition_date = min(datetime),
        order_dates = list(date(datetime))
    )
customers

## # A tibble: 1 x 4
##          email total_payment    acquisition_date order_dates
##          <chr>         <dbl>              <dttm>      <list>
## 1 xy@gmail.com        176.23 2013-01-05 05:10:00  <date [4]>

customers$order_dates

## [[1]]
## [1] "2013-01-05" "2013-02-07" "2013-07-10" "2013-08-12"
```